# Modifying a parameter pass to a script (Bash)

Tags: bash, arguments

I have been looking on Google for quite a while now and can't find anything that is matching what I need/want to do.

My objective is to write a script that takes two arguments. It will search through the first argument (which is a list) and detect if the second argument is already in it. For example:

list = /bin/foo:/bin/random:random

to add to list: /bin/foobar

Calling the script will produce the result of /bin/foo:/bin/random:random:/bin/foobar.

If the part to add to the list is already in the list then nothing will be changed of the original.

I have everything working up until the point where I want to modify the parameter I passed.

```
...
if [ $RUN = 1 ]; then
    echo $1
else
    $1="$NEWLIST"
fi
exit 0
```

This however produced an error. It says that the command isn't found and gives me the line number that $1="$NEWLIST" is on. What am I doing wrong here? How do I modify $1? Thanks!

edit:

```
$ PATH=/opt/bin:$PATH
$ ./scrip.sh PATH /user/opt/bin
$ /opt/bin:/user/opt/bin
```

This is what I would want as a result of the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

adymitruk already said it, but why do you want to assign to a parameter. Woudln't this do the trick?

```
if `echo :$1: | grep ":$2:" 1>/dev/null 2>&1`
then
  echo $1
else
  echo $1:$2
fi
```

Maybe this:

```
list="1:2:3:4"
list=`./script $list 5`;echo $list
```

BIG EDIT:

Use this script (called listadd for instance):

```
if ! `echo :${!1}: | grep ":$2:" 1>/dev/null 2>&1`
then
  export $1=${!1}:$2
fi
```

And source it from your shell. Result is the following (I hope this is what wsa intended):

```
lorenzo@enzo:~$ list=1:2:3:4
lorenzo@enzo:~$ source listadd list 3
lorenzo@enzo:~$ echo $list
1:2:3:4
lorenzo@enzo:~$ source listadd list 5
lorenzo@enzo:~$ echo $list
1:2:3:4:5
lorenzo@enzo:~$ list2=a:b:c
lorenzo@enzo:~$ source listadd list2 a
lorenzo@enzo:~$ echo $list2
a:b:c
lorenzo@enzo:~$ source listadd list2 d
lorenzo@enzo:~$ echo $list2
a:b:c:d
```

Comment: Hrmm maybe I left something out. What I want to happen after the script is called that every time I echo the list I want it to also show the modification the script did. Does that makes sense? So if I had

    list="1:2:3:4"

    ./script list 5

the program will echo the result. Then everytime I call 

    echo list
    1:2:3:4:5

will result.

Comment: you have to add `-q` to `grep`

Comment: @Op De Cirkel. I don't think device null will care much. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @yaegerbomb Do you mean "./script list 5" or "./script $list 5"?

Comment: @Hyperboreus the exercise says: "Write a shell function that takes two arguments: 1)the name of a shell variable and 2) a string to prepend to the list that the value of the shell variable only if that string is not already an element of the list."

Comment: @yaegerbomb OK, I edited again. Please tell me if I got it right now.

Comment: @Hyperboreus  I get an error that says 'Line 5: export: '1:2:3:4=:5': not a valid identifier. Something with the line export is not working on my terminal. Appreciate the help though!

Comment: @yaegerbomb strange. works with me on GNU bash, Version 4.2.8(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: @yaegerbomb Are you sure you call `source listadd list 5` and not `source listadd $list 5`?

Comment: @Hyperboreus Might be the problem. The schools version is 4.1.7 and unfortunately I have to run my script on that. I will consult with my prof tomorrow and hope it isn't due until after class or something. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @yaegerbomb Actually your error looks like one $ too much in the call. Look at my earlier comment please.

Comment: @Hyperboreus Yup, was calling it wrong from the command line. This worked. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 13):

To set the positional parameters `$1, $2, ...`, use the [`set`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin) command:

```
set foo bar baz
echo "$*"   # ==> foo bar baz
echo $1     # ==> foo

set abc def
echo "$*"   # ==> abc def
```

If you want to modify one positional parameter without losing the others, first store them in an array:

```
set foo bar baz
args=( "$@" )
args[1]="BAR"
set "${args[@]}"
echo "$*"   # ==> foo BAR baz
```

Comment: This is a saver, however, I'd advise to use "set --" to mitigate an issue when the first argument starts with a dash.

Answer (score 2):

First copy your parameters to local variables:

```
Arg1=$1
```

Then, where you are assigning leave off the $ on the variable name to the left of the =

You can't have a $ on the left hand side of an assignment. If you do, it's interpreting the contents of $1 as a command to run

hope this helps